# An argument in Hilbert's basis theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Hilbert's basis theorem : If $R$ is a Noetherian ring, then $R[X]$ is a Noetherian ring.

The following proof is from Fulton's algebraic curves. I am skipping some parts of the proof and coming directly to my doubt.

Proof: We first choose a set $J$ which contains all the leading coefficients of any ideal $I$ which we want to prove, is finitely generated. We prove that $J$ is an ideal in $R$ and hence finitely generated, say, $(a_1,\dots,a_r)$ with the corresponding polynomials $f_1,\dots, f_r$. To generate the elements of lower degree in $I$, we take other 'similar' sets $J_m  \; \forall m \leq N $ where $N $ is greater than the $\max\{ deg(f_1), \dots, deg(f_r)  \}$. We denote the corresponding polynomials for $J_m$ by $\{ f\}_{mj}$.

Next, we claim that $I$ is generated by $f_1,\dots, f_r$ and all $\{ f\}_{mj}$. Proof given in book: Let's call the latter as $I'$. We can easily see that $I'\subset I$. Suppose $I'$ were smaller than $I$; let $G$ be an element of $I$ of **lowest degree** that is
not in $I'$. If $deg(G) > N$, we can find polynomials $Q_i$ such that $\sum Q_iF_i$ and $G$ have the
same leading term.

argument:  But then $deg(G -  \sum Q_iF_i ) < deg G$, so $G - \sum Q_iF_i \in I'$, so $G \in I'$.

Doubt: I don't understand why the following is true? If  $deg(G -  \sum Q_iF_i ) < deg G$, then $G - \sum Q_iF_i \in I'$. It might be possible that both $I$ and $I'$ might have polynomials of all degree.

Comment: That element has smaller degree than $G$, which is an element of lowest degree not in $I'$, thus it must be in $I'$.

Comment: @metalspringpro that looks like an answer to me - would you care to record it in the answers below?

Comment: @KReiser Thanks for the suggestion; I went ahead and did that. I probably should have put it as an answer to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't want to proceed with lowest degree element. Even if you don't start with that, assume $G \in I \backslash I'$ whose degree is, say, $m >0$. Based on the similar argument, you can say that the degree of $G - \sum F_iQ_i$ is less than degree of $G$. You can keep doing this until you get to 0 in which case, we have a $constant  \in I \backslash I'$. Hence, $I = k[X_1,\dots, X_n]$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

We know $I' \subseteq I$ and we suppose they are not equal. Then there is an $x \in I$ that is not in $I'$.  Each such $x$ has a degree, and thus I may choose such an $x$ of minimal degree and call it $G$. However, the element $G-\sum Q_iF_i$ is obviously in $I$, and, by construction, has smaller degree than $G$.  Thus, by the choice of $G$, $G-\sum Q_iF_i$ must be in $I'$.

Just to illustrate the point about choosing an element of smallest degree: if $R=k[x,y]$, $I=(x,y^3)$ and $J=(x,y)$, then $I \subsetneq J$. Even though both of these ideals contain polynomials of every (nonzero) degree, I can still choose an element of $J$ not contained in $I$, e.g., $y^2$.  To choose an element of smallest degree of $J$ that is not in $I$ could be to take $y$ or $x+y$, there are many, but the degree of such an element must be $1$.

Comment: No, I am not satisfied with this line of argument. That is why I asked this question. For e.g. to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number, we can always contradict that any rational number $n/m$ (if it is equal to $\sqrt{2}$) would be further reduced (i.e. there is a common factor between $n,m$) but you can't reduce a natural number infinite number of times and hence the contraction. I don't want to go with the argument that you start with $n/m$ which is non-reducible and after 1 stage you prove that it it reducible.

Comment: My point is that $I$ and $I'$ can have polynomial of all degrees and hence it does not make sense to assume " let $G$ be an element of $I$ of lowest degree that is not in $I′$. "

Comment: @MUH Your phrasing of your question made it seem to me that your confusion was with a different portion of the argument. I will edit my answer to address your concerns here.

Comment: @MUH Just to add one more remark, I believe your confusion comes around what is meant by "let $G$ be an element of $I$ of lowest degree that is not int  $I$". This statement does not mean to find a degree that $I'$ misses and choose an element of $I$ of that degree. Instead, it means look on all the elements of $I \setminus I'$ and choose one of smallest degree.